# awk version issue - convert hex to decimal

Tags: parsing, bash, sed, awk

I usually write scripts on my mac and then once it is ready, I sftp them to my test box at work. The issue I am facing here is that I have a stream of data that is an I.P address in hex format. I am using mix of sed and awk to parse it and convert it into a more readable format.

```
$echo $content12
cb5c860100000000000000000000000000 

[DoD@MBP-13~] echo $content12 | 
sed -e 's/../&./g' -e 's/.$//' | sed 's/[0-9a-z][0-9a-z]/0x&/g' | 
awk -F"." '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf ("%d\n", $i)}' |
awk '{if (NR<5) printf $0; printf "."}' | sed 's/\.\.*$//'
203.92.134.1
```

When I ported this to my test box at work, the script did not work as expected.

```
$echo $content12 | 
sed -e 's/../&./g' -e 's/.$//' | sed 's/[0-9a-z][0-9a-z]/0x&/g' | 
awk -F"." '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf ("%d\n", $i)}' | 
awk '{if (NR<5) printf $0; printf "."}' | sed 's/\.\.*$//'
0.0.0.0
```

**Version of awk and uname on my mac -**

```
[DoD@MBP-13~] awk --version
awk version 20070501

[DoD@MBP-13~] uname -a
Darwin MBP-13.local 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011;     
root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

**Version of awk and uname on my test box at work -**

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2005 Free Software Foundation

$uname -a
Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is this something I can fix with minor changes. I am still very new to UNIX environment so my one-liner may seem abnormally long to you. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--non-decimal-data` option of `gawk` to cause it to handle octal and hex numbers in the input:

```
$ echo 0x10 | gawk --non-decimal-data '{ printf "%d", $1 }'
16
```

versus:

```
$ echo 0x10 | gawk '{ printf "%d", $1 }'
0
```

Answer (score 1):

In essence this problem boils down to feeding `printf` a string of parameters.`printf` is a shell builtin so:

```
echo "cb5c860100000000000000000000000000" |
sed 's/\(.\{8\}\).*/\1/;s/../"0x&" /g;s/^/printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" /'|sh
203.92.134.1
```

In GNU sed you can evaluate the pattern space, like so:

```
echo "cb5c860100000000000000000000000000" |
sed 's/\(.\{8\}\).*/\1/;s/../"0x&" /g;s/^/printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" /e'
203.92.134.1
```

In programming, I've found the hardest thing is not coding but saying what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the GNU `awk(1)` implementation doesn't handle `0x11` as an argument to `printf()` as you've implemented it:

```
$ echo cb5c860100000000000000000000000000 | sed -e 's/../&./g' -e 's/.$//' |
  sed 's/[0-9a-z][0-9a-z]/0x&/g'
0xcb.0x5c.0x86.0x01.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00.0x00
$ echo cb5c860100000000000000000000000000 | sed -e 's/../&./g' -e 's/.$//' |
  sed 's/[0-9a-z][0-9a-z]/0x&/g' |
  awk -F"." '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf ("%d\n", $i)}'
0
0
0
...
```

The `mawk(1)` installed on my system (by Mike Brennan) -- an alternative to GNU `awk(1)` that claims to be smaller, faster, and still POSIX 1003.2 (draft 11.3) compliant -- *does* interpret this as you expected:

```
$ echo cb5c860100000000000000000000000000 | sed -e 's/../&./g' -e 's/.$//' |
  sed 's/[0-9a-z][0-9a-z]/0x&/g' |
  mawk -F"." '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf ("%d\n", $i)}' |
  mawk '{if (NR<5) printf $0; printf "."}' | sed 's/\.\.*$//'
203.92.134.1$
```

If you're lucky enough to also have `mawk(1)` installed and available, this solution may be suitable.

Comment: Thanks sarnold. Unfortunately I don't have that installed on my test box at work. I will have to get with sysadmins to have it deployed. I have used @Rick's answer as it was easy to implement.

Comment: I like @Rick's answer too, it is far less disruptive than mine. I was busy reading the `gawk(1)` manpage to try to figure out how to use `CONVFMT` when I saw his answer, so I gave up then and there. :)